# What is the motivation for "continuity in the sense of distributions"?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $M$ be a compact (real) manifold and let $\Omega^m_c(M)$ be the compactly supported $m$-forms on $M$.  Apparently a linear map $T : \Omega^m_c(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous "in the sense of distributions" if $T(\omega_k) \to 0$ whenever $\omega_k$ is a sequence of smooth forms, all supported on a fixed compact set, such that all the derivatives of all the coefficients of the $\omega_k$ uniformly approach zero as $k \to \infty$.

Is there a more natural, less arbitrary-sounding way of describing the same topology on $\Omega^m_c(M)$?

Comment: A linear map $T$ on $\Omega_c^m$ is continuous, iff for each compact set $K$ the restriction $T_{|K}$ is continuous, where the space $\Omega_c^m(M_{|K})$ carries the topology of uniform convergence. Does this sound more natural?

Comment: What does $\Omega^m_c(M|_K)$ denote, exactly?

Comment: The smooth forms on $M$ supported in $K$.